# Scrollable plugin doesnt work

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools, jquery-scrollable

I am using Jquery tools scrollable plugin.
I want to scroll through a list of images one at a time on mouse wheel movement.
But am not able to achieve this through the code I am working on.
Please help.

Edit : Scrolling occurs through press of UP and DOWN arrows but not through mousewheel.

The HTML :

```
<div class = "scrollable vertical">
    <div class = "items">
        <div><div class = "item"></div></div>
        <div><div class = "item"></div></div>
        <div><div class = "item"></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.scrollable').scrollable({vertical : true, mousewheel : true});
});
```

CSS :

```
.scrollable {
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
}
.scrollable .items {
position:absolute;
height:20000em;
}
```

Comment: You've mis-typed "mousehweel", could that be it? Can you briefly explain what happens?

Comment: @Simon Adcock : Ya i corrected it. Still doesnt work. No Scrolling doesnt occur. The div with item class contains images. I want them to scroll corresponding to mousewheel movement. But no vertical scrolling takes place.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702563/mouse-wheel-behaving-strangely-with-jquery-tools-scrollable-plugin

Comment: @imonas : I read that already.. I want to scroll through... Not actually click a button to do that...